# TableView cell is showing the last uploaded image to parse for all the cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a PFQueryTableViewController, which downloads my images from parse.

I had it working all correctly, displaying the correct image in all the cells, but today I have added a header cell too and now I have the headerCell displaying the correct information and also changing(which is exactly how I want it to be) but now the cell that displays the imageView shows the latest image uploaded for all of the cells & not different image as it should do...?!

Here is the code which controlls my tableview..But I cant understand what is wrong!

object, is var object: PFObject?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 46
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objects!.count
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostHeader") as! PostHeaderTableViewCell


        let object = objects![section]
        let username = object.objectForKey("user")?.objectForKey("username") as? String
        headerCell.usernameLabel.text = username!.capitalizedString


        let dataFormatter: NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -4)
        NSLog("Time Ago: %@", dataFormatter.shortTimeAgoSinceNow())
        headerCell.timeLabel.text = dataFormatter.shortTimeAgoSinceDate((object.createdAt)!)

        if (object.objectForKey("user")!.objectForKey("profilePicture") != nil)
        {
            let userImageFile:PFFile = object.objectForKey("user")!.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                headerCell.postProfilePicture.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                headerCell.postProfilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = 0.1 * headerCell.postProfilePicture.bounds.size.width
                headerCell.postProfilePicture.clipsToBounds = true

            })
        }


        return headerCell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return 1
    }




    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell?
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BaseTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel?.text = object?.objectForKey("title") as? String

        let imageFile = object?.objectForKey("imageFile") as? PFFile
        cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
        cell.cellImageView?.file = imageFile
        cell.cellImageView.loadInBackground()


        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        if indexPath.row + 1 > self.objects?.count
        {
            return 44
        }
        let height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        return height
    }
```

If anyone can help, That would be amazing!!

Comment: Not sure if this relates to your problem but you're returning many different sections and only one row for each section so the image will always be the first one in your data source array.

Comment: hi @pbush25 I have tried adding 2 etc not sure if that would make a difference, but what that did was show 1 headercell, and 2images(the latest 2) and that was just repeated for as many cell I had!

Comment: Is your intention to have as many sections as you do images?

Comment: @pbush25 well I want to display as many cell's&headerCell's as images uploaded on parse, so If I have 30 different images uploaded to Parse, I would like to display 30 of each cell, showing all the different images(and not just the last one to be uploaded like now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue has to do with the override `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method that you're using. Because the generic `PFQueryTableViewController` is intended for only one section, when you use that method with the signature `(tableView, indexPath, object)` instead of the default one with signature `(tableView, indexPath)` the method will always pull the # of images that you returned in `numberOfRowsInSection`. What I suggest you do instead is use the regular `cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!` and then get the object based on the `indexPath`.

It would look like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BaseTableViewCell
    if let object = objects![indexPath.row] as? PFObject {
        cell.titleLabel?.text = object?.objectForKey("title") as? String

        let imageFile = object.objectForKey("imageFile") as? PFFile
        cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
        cell.cellImageView?.file = imageFile
        cell.cellImageView.loadInBackground()
    }
    return cell
}
```

This will then get you the image for the appropriate index path that you're looking for, rather than always using the first one.

You can also try printing the `indexPath.row` in that method when it's called so you can see if the `indexPath` is changing.

EIDT: Actually it seems like even that may not work. You can try to follow the tutorial [here](https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections), but they explicitly mention that a `PFQueryTableViewController`is not meant to work with multiple sections. You're probably better off subclassing a regular `UITableViewController`

Comment: hmm ok, I'll give this a go and let you know!